# Parse a file to find inactive elements

Tags: python, file, parsing

Hi I have gather the current configuration of our nic bonding in all of our server and put it on a file. example of the data below:

File Name: temp2

```
Server1
Currently Active Slave: eth0
Slave Interface: eth0
Slave Interface: eth1
Server2
Currently Active Slave: eth1
Slave Interface: eth0
Slave Interface: eth1
ServerN
....
....
```

sorry I seldom use python so I consider my self a newbie, I would like to write a python script the will read the file and check each server print only that is not active interface. Any suggestion? So far below is what I have started it just read the file, got stuck on how to print only the interface that is not Current Active.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4

content = open('/home/Workspace/temp2', 'r')
print content.read()

# Compare the Active from the two interface;then 
print Not Active

# >> Example: Server1
# >> Current Active: eth0
print eth1

content.close()
```

Comment: This is a well formed question, but note that your title (*"python script to find out which network interface is not the current active on network bonding"*) describes your goal, but it would be better to describe what problem you're currently trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need a list of server names so we can keep track what server we are currently reading.

If the line is a server, then we look what interface is active. We parse each line and if the interface is inactive, we append this to the list.

```
names = ['Server1', 'Server2', 'Server3']
inactives = {}

for name in names:
    inactives[name] = []

currentServer = None
for line in open('/home/Workspace/temp2'):
    if line.strip() in names:
        currentServer = line.strip()
        active = None

    if line.startswith('Currently Active Slave: '):
        active = line.split(':')[-1].strip()

    if active and line.startswith('Slave Interface: '):
        interface = line.split(':')[-1].strip()

        if interface != active:
            inactives[currentServer].append(interface)

print(inactives)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will parse the file for you:

```
serv, intf = None, None
for line in open('/home/Workspace/temp2'):
    if line.startswith('Server'):
        serv = line.strip()
    elif line.startswith('Currently Active Slave: '):
        intf = line.split(':')[-1].strip()
    if serv is not None and intf is not None:
        print('{} - {}'.format(serv, intf))
        serv, intf = None, None
```

Comment: hi sorry the actual file is below, how do I change "if line.startswith('Server'):" with the real server name?
<pre>
BATMAN3
Currently Active Slave: eth1
Slave Interface: eth0
Slave Interface: eth1
======================
SUPERMAN3
Currently Active Slave: eth0
Slave Interface: eth0
Slave Interface: eth1
======================
NINJA2
Currently Active Slave: eth0
Slave Interface: eth0
Slave Interface: eth1
======================
</pre>

Comment: Here is what I'm trying to do, but its not working..

   ` file = open("/home/Workspace/rtcis_bond_list", 'r')
for line in file:
    if line.startswith('Currently Active Slave:'):
        cintf = line.split(':')[-1].strip()
    if line.startswith('Slave Interface:'):
        sintf = line.split(':')[-1].strip()
    if "cintf" != "sintf":
         print sintf
`

Comment: sorry trying to add backtick so that the code would be formatted properly but not sure why its not working..